# How to preserve extensions in Firefox with VSCode and request Launch

Tags: reactjs, firefox, visual-studio-code, react-devtools

I'm attempting to debug a React app with React Dev Tools and Firefox Developer Edition. I can't install React Dev Tools to the profile Firefox is using when it is launched via VSCode. I have React Dev Tools installed when I launch Firefox myself via opening it in /Applications.

However, when I run the below `launch.json` profile, there are no extensions shown under Preferences -> Extensions & Themes -> Extensions in FireFox after it launches.

```
{
  "name": "Launch localhost",
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "reAttach": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

However, I can follow the directions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug) and launch Firefox with the terminal and attach my debugger to it. This Profile has React Dev Tools and it works fine running:

```
/Applications/Firefox\ Developer\ Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -start-debugger-server
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "name": "Attach",
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "attach",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

But how do I make the first one work with a `launch` request instead of `attach`? From reading it seems to have something to do with the profile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by adding to my launch.json:

```
"profile": "my-firefox-profile"
```

Firefox can have miltiple profiles installed. You can check them by typing `about:profiles` in firefoxes adress bar.
It will show you a list of profiles. The one marked as `Default profile: yes` should be the one to choose.

[image]

My launch.json now looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Firefox",
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "reAttach": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:4300",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "profile": "default-release-1"
    },
```

Background:

Firefox profiles hold settings like browsing history, bookmarks  - and most importantly - add-ons. By telling VSCode to use a specific profile it serves with the installed plugins.

This will also work if you have the same problem with Angular or Vue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, I had to also add the following to `launch.json` to make Firefox launch with the specified profile.

```
"keepProfileChanges": true
```

I am using VSCode 1.52.1 and Firefox 84.0.2.

Comment: Why did you have to add this parameter? What happened without it?